# Do votes keep the question in the "active" pile?

Tags: support

Does upvoting on a question keep the question in the "active" tab?

Comment: No, they don't. Edits and new answers 'bump' the question back to the top of the active tab, but that's it with one exception: unanswered questions will routinely, but not very often, be brought back to the front by the SE Network (i.e. the user Community).

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info) for a list of things that bump a question and some relevant links.

Comment: However, the upvotes influence whether question is a [hot question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions). IIRC there also used to be [interesting tab](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin!!!